# Algorithm for decomposing abelian p groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, computational-algebra

I'm trying to write a computer program to determine the primary cyclic structure of $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$. However the standard proof requires a very computational intensive step.

More explicitly the standard proof algorithm has 2 main parts:

1. Decompose G into a direct sum of it's sylow p-subgroups
2. Decompose each sylow p-subgroup into a direct sum of cylic p-groups

The first step is a very straightfoward calculation, however in most standard proofs of the abelian group structure theorem the 2nd step goes like this:

$$\text{Let} \ G \ \text{be a finite abelian p-group and choose} \ x \in G \text{ with maximal order}$$
$$\text{Then G = } \langle x \rangle \oplus H$$

where this $H$ subgroup is determined by a recursive step.

Translating this into an concrete algorithm, this means that i need to find a maximal order element in $G$ and then a maximal order element whose generated group dosen't intersect the first and so on recursively picking the maximal order element that dosen't intersect the direct sum of the previous.

This seems **terrible**. I don't think there's any way of doing this that isn't just checking the order of every element individually and comparing them one by one to find a maximal element, and then manually checking for intersections of their cyclic groups untill we're done.

I can think of a few simplifications: for exemple if I actually do check every element's order and they're all equal to $p$ then $$G = \bigoplus_{i = 0}^{n-1} \mathbb{Z}_p \quad (|G| = p^n)$$

Also, of course, if there is an element with order $p^n$ then $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ is cyclic.

My question is: is there a good (better) algorithm for finding the cyclic decomposition of abelian p-groups (p-primary groups) *or* how can the standard proof algorithm be simplified as to be less computational intensive?

Comment: Can't you use the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: The structure of these groups is well-known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: If you want a general algorithm for an abelian $p$-group (not knowing that it came from a multiplicative group of integers), then you need to be clearer about how the group is given as input, etc.

Comment: It did not occur to me that (AxB)^x = A^x x B^x. So yeah, I can just use the Chinese remainder theorem and the prime case.